# Remove all text before first occurence of specific characeter in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Look at following vector:

```
x <- c("MED - This means medic - somecode123", "HIV" - This means HIV -somecode456")
```

Now I want the vector: containing the values

```
 This means medic - somecode123` 
 This means HIV - somecode1456
```

I seem not able to solve this using `gsub`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Match the pattern of one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`) followed by `-` and white space (`\\s+`) and replace it with `""`.

```
sub('\\S+\\s+-\\s+', "", x)
#[1] "This means medic - somecode123" "This means HIV -somecode456"
```