# R-How to get specific string value in data frame header

Tags: r, regex

I have data frame df ,How to return value from string after some first character or number.

My data frame.

```
ID   Name  Name.FirstName   Name.Last.Name  Age

1     rosy     ton            P            23

2     Jhon     peter          N            22
```

my expected data frame.

```
ID   Name   FirstName      Last.Name     Age

1     rosy     ton            P           23

2     Jhon     peter          N           22
```

I need to remove before first (.) value from dataframe Header only .

dput

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2), Name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Jhon", 
"rosy"), class = "factor"), Name.FirstName = structure(c(2L, 
1L), .Label = c("peter", "ton"), class = "factor"), Name.Last.Name = structure(c(2L, 
1L), .Label = c("N", "P"), class = "factor"), Age = c(23, 22)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Name", "Name.FirstName", "Name.Last.Name", "Age"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all text before first occurence of specific characeter in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158204/remove-all-text-before-first-occurence-of-specific-characeter-in-r) OR [Use gsub remove all string before first white space in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767164/use-gsub-remove-all-string-before-first-white-space-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]*`) from the start (`^`) of the column name followed by a `.` and replace it with blank (`""`).  As `.` is a metacharacter i.e. it matches for any character, we escape to get the literal meaning of the character

```
names(df) <- sub("^[^.]*\\.", "", names(df))
names(df)
#[1] "ID"        "Name"      "FirstName" "Last.Name" "Age"
```

Comment: ,Thanks its working as in expected.